# Functional model with multiple branches

Tags: keras

I am trying to add multiple classification branches on top of a InceptionV3 network. I am using a imageGenerator but can't seem to set it up right.

I have one imageGenerator for both branches, reading data from one root directory.

My root directories(train, test) are structured like:

- class a (e.g. Fabric)

  - Cotton
  - Leather
- class b (.e.g Color)

  - Black
  - Blue

The code I use to initialize the generators is:

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('./train',
                                                   target_size = target_size,
                                                   batch_size = batch_size,
                                                   class_mode = 'categorical',
                                                   shuffle=True)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('./test',
                                                   target_size = target_size,
                                                   batch_size = batch_size,
                                                   class_mode = 'categorical',
                                                   shuffle=True)
```

I'm not sure how I would train each branch in my network using the training data for that class.

Answer (score 0):

You want to train a network for multi-label classification.

You **do not need** to have multiple branches; You can train only one neural network to tell you both the color and the type of the clothes.

My suggestion is to have a look at this blog, it's exactly what you need:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/07/multi-label-classification-with-keras/

Note that you may need to restructure your training set, i.e. for example, to have a folder with blue dress, another folder with blue jeans, then a folder with red dress etc.

However, if you do need to have multiple branches, you should definitely have a look at this: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/04/keras-multiple-outputs-and-multiple-losses/

Comment: Is my assumption correct that in your example dataset, the model would perform less good in unseen combinations like red jeans? Because that is what I am trying to achieve. I think that blog you linked also mentions this.

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct because the model is trained on combinations of clothes and colors. So practically when you feed it an "unknown combination", it would be like you feed your model unknown data. For example, for a simple **multi-class classification**, if you train your neural network to distinguish between shirts, jeans and scarfs, you cannot expect it to know how a "jacket" looks like. This is also available for multi-label classification, but since we have multi-labels we now refer to combinations(red+jeans, blue+dress etc).

Comment: So in that case i do need a multi branch network, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure how multiple inputs would help my case (perhaps it's my lack of knowledge!). The data I feed my network is still of the same 'type' of image, however I am trying to make predictions on different aspects of that image. Could you maybe take another look at the problem I initially presented? I still think the approach in itself was correct. Thanks for your time either way!

Comment: Yes you are right, I diverged a bit from the initial problem and mistook your initial task for another one. The solution to your problem is this one https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/04/keras-multiple-outputs-and-multiple-losses/. You can see in the article as it clearly creates two different branches, one for color and one for clothes. I think this is the final answer :D. I will modify my first answer to include the link to the second article.